# How long have the Lookup and Locate methods of TDataset been around?

Tags: delphi, dataset

I'm working on modernizing and fixing bugs in the codebase of a Delphi 4-era program written by someone else.  A lot of the code is kinda scary by modern standards, and I can't help but wonder if some of the things I'm seeing are there because the original author didn't know about certain standard library features, or if they weren't available.

One of the more obnoxious "patterns" I see all over the app looks like this:

```
table := TClientDataset.Create;
with table do
begin
  CloneCursor(dmDatabase.OriginalTable, false, true);
  filtered := true;
  active := true;
  first;
  while not EOF do
  begin
    if fieldByName('whatever').AsString = 'some criteria' then break;
    next;
  end;
  if EOF then exit;
  //do something based on the current row of the dataset
  table.free;
end;
```

Almost every one of these groups could be replaced by a one-line call to either `Lookup` or `Locate` on the original dataset, with no need for an intermediary CDS at all.  That makes me wonder, were these methods available back in the D4 days?  When were `Lookup` and `Locate` first added?

Comment: If 'some criteria' is not found then `table` is not freed?

Comment: @Jrl: Like I said, some of this code is kinda scary by modern standards. :P  But that was basically recreated as a general pattern from memory.  try-finally blocks may or may not actually be present.  There are some, but not nearly as many as there ought to be.

Comment: This looks like code written by someone who had learned just enough delphi to get the job done, and knew exactly one (brute force way) to do things. Even in Delphi 1 he could have written a helper function, and avoided copy-paste-disease.

Comment: I remember using that kind of pattern cause Locate did not work as expected with some kind of fields. Not sure now of which ones, neither if this is the motivation behind this code...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lookup and Locate were introduced in Delphi 2.  It looks like the original author simply didn't take advantage of them.

Comment: +1; File D2-CS-2.0\SOURCE\VCL\DB.PAS:
810         function Locate(const KeyFields: string; const KeyValues: Variant;

Comment: @Jeroen: *WHY* do you have the VCL source for Delphi 2 handy enough to search in such a way?  `D-:`

Comment: @afrazier: doesn't everyone?  :)

Comment: Confirmed, definitely not in Delphi 1 VCL. And I still have Delphi 1 because I still have some 16bit apps I support. Urk. I even still cross compile code between Delphi 1 and Delphi 2010. Try doing that with VB 3 and VB.Net!

Comment: @afrazier: because I keep copies of old stuff :) Actually: that comes in very handy when helping clients that use older versions of Delphi.

Answer (score 6):

Seems the Original programmer wanted to make sure that the row pointer is not changed
at all. Doing `Locate` (or `Lookup`) would change the row pointer, provoking all kinds 
of data events (Datasource.OnDataChange, Dataset.AfterScroll and so on).

Doing the search with `TClientDataset.CloneCursor`, none of the these events ger triggered on the `dmDatabase.OriginalTable`  and there's no need to reload the data from database.

Seems to me that is the intention. TClientDataset was presented on D3. And *cloned cursors* are a kind
of advanced feature - and need the `dmDatabase.OriginalTable` to be a CDS too.

Comment: I would probably use DisableControls/EnableControls and bookmarks rather than cloning the cursor for each operation like this.

Comment: `Lookup` does not change the row pointer.  `Locate` does, but in a few cases this is taking place on the original dataset, without the CDS/`CloneCursor` stuff, and it basically is a reimplementation of `Locate`.

Comment: But why didn't they use `Locate` or `LookUp` on the clone?

Comment: Another good question: why this is repeated all over the place (as Mason says) instead of a single search function? I know it's pretty possible - unless with preallocated vararrays in (R.I.P.) Delphi.net, which is troublesome - with `locate` - I even done one this way.